# DLL Reference Issue with TFS Build server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild, build-server

I'm trying to implement TFS Build server in my VS 2013 Project. But got stuck with some third party dll reference issue. Source structure in my local folder and TFS is same and dll hint path in csproj file is set to relative path.

[image: My Build Defenition]

[image: Project File]

[image: Error message]

Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: You will probably have to turn it into a local nuget package and reference it that way. Its fairly simple to do and is the Microsoft recommended way to handle local dlls.

Comment: These are the custom dlls associated with our custom project template. Its not possible to turn everything to nuget package as i have to implement build server for a number of project.

Comment: Well then make sure your dll's are persisted in TFS and map the correct path as per your screenshot 1. Again, using a nuget package is simple, you can persist the package in tfs, and its easy to version. It does not add much work at all.

Comment: My dlls are there in correct folder of TFS as well. I think its not the issue. Is there any problem with my Build definition or project file settings?

Comment: Its not that they are in the wrong place in TFS but that the build def. is not pulling them in when it executes. That is what you are defining in screenshot 1, what to pull in from TFS and where to place it locally before the next action (usually compile) starts. If that is not configured correctly you will either not pull in your dependencies OR pull them in but not in the expected location.

Comment: Ok, What should be the change i have to do in configuration for solving these errors? Are you getting any thing from above screen shots or do i need to share any other configuration of the project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106492/discussion-between-rinesh-and-igor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I got it. I have changed the relative path of hint path in .csproj file to TFS Specific path using `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` . i,e., `..\..\Common\Myclass.dll` is changed to `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Common\Myclass.dll`. It solved my issue and got a successful build.

Comment: This solution worked with me when I used it inside (Windows Forms) project. But It doesn't work when I used it inside (Class Library) project that uses external DLLs.